# Search for nearest int value in sorted array <= given value from right

Tags: c++, windows-10

How to modify program to return for value = 8 index 8 i.e. first index of "8" from right (and not index 6 now i.e. first index of "8" from left). For value = 7 program correctly return index 5 (array value 6).

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int arr[10]{0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9};
int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);


int main()
{
for (int i = 0; i <= arr_size; i++)
{
    printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");

int left = 0;
int right = arr_size - 1;
int middle = 0; 
int value = 8 ; 
int x = 0;
int index = 0;



//* Searching for value in ascending sorted array
while (left <= right) {
    middle = (left + right) / 2;
    if (arr[middle] <= value) {
        x = arr[middle];
        index = middle;
    }
    if (value > arr[middle]) {
        left = middle + 1;
    }
    else {
        right = middle - 1;
    }
}
printf("Found %i at position %i\n", x, index);

}
```

Comment: Just use `std::upper_bound()`, btw this is pretty much C code (except include iostream, but that is not used)

Comment: `int arr[10]{0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9};` - Why is this not `std::array`?  `int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` - no, please don't. Why is this not `arr.size()` or at least `std::size(arr)`? This is C code compiled with a C++ compiler, *not* idiomatic C++ (and that's *not* a complement).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::upper_bound()`:

```
int arr[] = {0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9};
auto beg = std::begin(arr);
auto it = std::upper_bound( beg, std::end(arr), 8 );
if( it == beg ) {
    std::cout << "no value less than 8 found" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "index is " << std::distance( beg, it ) - 1 << std::endl;
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/XawiC5)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But how to modify it without using special directives e.g. "upper_bound". I need to program it in x64 assembler.

Comment: @Ziggi documentation provides 2 possible implementations of this function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound